# Ubuntu not booting after installation

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 from USB stick successfully (As the only OS on my computer), but after I restarted my PC, my computer tried to boot from CD. I've inserted my old Ubuntu CD that I got from one book and choose "boot from hard disk". Then it written (on black screen of course) "booting from hard disk" or something like that. In next line I had flashing _,but I couldn't type anything. What can I do to at least try re-installing Ubuntu?

Note: I don't have internet access on that PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hold shift during boot and you will be presented with GRUB menu. Hihglight Ubuntu, press F10 to edit the entry, find word `quiet` in it and append `nomodeset` after it. 
Ubuntu 13.04 community drivers have real problems with KMS. If this helps, remember it is for one boot only.